# Find $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{|\sin x|}{x}$

Tags: limits, functions

Can I say that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1 \implies \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{|\sin x|}{x}=1$$?

Comment: No. Look at $x < 0$.

Comment: Can you say that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac xx=1\implies \lim_{x\to0}\frac{|x|}x=1$$?

Answer (score 3):

Exercise: show that 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{|\sin x|}{x}
$$ does not exists.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{|\sin(x)|}x=1$$

But on the other side,

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{|\sin(x)|}x=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{|\sin(-x)|}{-x}=-\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{|\sin(x)|}x=-1$$

Thus, the limit cannot exist.

Comment: Why is this $$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{|\sin(x)|}x=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{|\sin(-x)|}{-x}$$ correct? Is this a known thing?

Comment: @S.Peter Think about it for a bit.  Taking the limit from the left side is equal to the negative of the limit from the right side...

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

When $x$ changes sign, $x$ will change sign.

When $x$ changes sign, $|f(x)|$ will not change sign.

Answer (score -1):

I know three ways to attack this. The [sandwich theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), [L'Hospital's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html) or [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).
I will show you the way with the Taylor series. Let's look at the series expansion of $\sin{x}$ at the point $0$:
$$\sin{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+...
$$
Now you can see that
$$
\frac{\sin{x}}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n}=1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+...
$$
Taking the limit now will be trivial if you belief in Taylor series. Maybe you can proof the series expansion of $\sin{x}$.